# I want to scrape anchors a from container class with scrapy

Tags: python, web, scrapy, screen-scraping

```
  <div class="breadcrumbs">
<div class="container">
    
                        <a href="https://www.simple-dress.com/" title="Go to Home Page">Home</a>
                                    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span>
        
    
                        <a href="https://www.simple-dress.com/cheap-special-occasion-dresses.html" title="">Special Occasion Dresses</a>
                                    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span>
        
    
                        <a href="https://www.simple-dress.com/evening-dresses.html" title="">Evening Dresses</a>
                                    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span>
        
    
                        <a href="https://www.simple-dress.com/formal-evening-dresses.html" title="">Formal Evening Dresses</a>
                                    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span>
        
    
                        <strong>Deep V-neck Yellow Long Prom Dress Sleeveless Satin Evening Dress</strong>
                    
        </div>
```

I want to scrape the third anchor from container class but I am unable to scape that one I used `response.css('.breadcrumbs div.container a').getall()`  this selector to scrape all anchors but I get only first I am beginner I need help to scrape all these achors

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple using XPath expressions.
If you want to get anchor by position:

```
third_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]/a[3]/@href').get()
```

If you want to get anchor by the text of the link:

```
evening_dresses_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]/a[.="Evening Dresses"]/@href').get()
```